# Settings for a controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

In a template, I'm using a directive to populate a special tag  with a partial html file.

template.html

```
<foobar></foobar>
```

foobar.html

```
<div ng-controller="Foobar">
...
</div>
```

Now, I need to display 2 foobars in another template :

template2.html

```
<div class="container">
  <foobar></foobar> <!-- uses Foobar controller 1 -->
  <foobar></foobar> <!-- uses Foobar controller 2 -->
</div>
```

They are using their own Foobar controller, but what is the common way to "specialize" each Foobar controller instance? Can I use attributes for that? (for instance `<foobar service-type="foo"></foobar>`)

My idea is to make my controller 1 uses a specific angular service while my controller 2 uses another service, depending on, for instance, a variable named "serviceType".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you can use attributes for that.

Either in combination with an isolated scope...

```
scope: {
  'serviceType': '@', // simply via text binding ...
  'service': '='      // ... or two way binding (may only work with generic services)
},
```

... or by checking attributes in your link function.

```
link: {
  post: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    // Put it in scope to use it in the controller
    scope.serviceType = attrs.serviceType;
  }
}
```

Downside of the non generic way (text binding or attrs) is, that you need to inject all the services you may need into the directive or controller.

Comment: Arggg, you're a nice person :) I realize "RTFM" would have been an appropriate answer for my newb question. Thanks!